# Radiocarbon Dating; 200 year old wood sample what accuracy may I expect?

Tags: radiation, estimation, half-life

We have an old family house whose age is relatively unknown. By other non-scientific estimates I'd put it 150 to 200 years old.

A lot of the beams / columns etc. are wooden. Would it be possible to use Radiocarbon C14 dating to get a good estimate? I've seen C-dating used for ancient samples (BC etc.) but can it be used for 150-200 year old samples as well?

So far as the principle goes there shouldn't be any trouble right?

[image]

Also, any references  / equations to tell me how accurate an estimate on (say) a 200 year old sample may be?

Of course, one must assume the wood was used not too long after it was cut down I suppose. Sample amount is not a problem: some older beams are being cut down so I have about a kilogram of sample wood from a column.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: Of course, you'll only get the time when the wood was cut, and not when the house was finished construction. However, you could ask a construction worker or something related to construction to estimate how long your house would have taken to construct.

Comment: Very closely related to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346525/

Comment: Limitations of the methods: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating

Comment: Carbon dating is calibrated using data from tree rings.  For example, if you cut down an old tree today, you can see the growth rings going back many years.  You can then carbon date each ring and use the data to calibrate other readings.  You can do this further back than the lifetime of any current tree by matching the patterns of overlapping older samples.  If you have sufficient local samples you can be very accurate.  In your case, since your samples are trees, if you have a big enough sample and a good local database, you might get the actual year that the tree was cut.

Answer (score 1):

The basic formulae that are required for radioisotopes and nuclear half-life:

$N={N_0\over 2^n}$ ,

where $N$ represents the mass of radioisotope remaining, $N_0$ represents the mass of radioisotope at the beginning, and $n$ is the amount of half-lives that have passed. Furthermore,

$n={\Delta t \over \lambda}$ ,

where $\Delta t$ represents the time elapsed (or change in time), and $\lambda$ represents the half-life (in years).

This is enough information to calculate the age of any organic, or living material, up to an age of around 40 000 to 50 000 years (i.e. it is very reliable for your $\approx$ 200 year old wood). For your situation, all that is known is the half-life of carbon-14. To continue further, carbon daters find the ratio between carbon-14 and carbon-12 (which does not decay) to find $N$ and $N_0$. Their methods of finding the ratio is extremely accurate, so unless $\Delta t$ is under 20 years, I suspect radiocarbon dating will work.

Hope this helps, I know I've repeated things that you know but in case there's anything you missed.

Comment: Any thoughts on what accuracy I may expect at a 200 year sample? Nearest year?

Comment: A recent study by the National Institute of Justice showed that the accuracy of carbon dating on human remains from the past 60 years had an error of about 3 years. Until probably 500 years, that error of 1.5 years would decrease as the decay of carbon-14 becomes more reliable. That being said, I'd expect a 200 year old sample to have an error of around 3 to 10 years.

Comment: Material can be dated accurately over the last 60 years because of nuclear testing in the 50s/60s. Your analysis naively assumes that the natural radioactive carbon doesn't vary: it does and has been decreasing over the last few hundred years at roughly the same rate as the carbon-14 decay.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you, Rob Jeffries. However, I assumed that this would be like a question you'd receive in a test. In that context, my analysis should be correct. Very good job in spotting the omitted facts in my answer.